# not able to do copy activity with bit value in azure data factory without column mapping for sink as postgresql

Tags: type-conversion, azure-data-factory

I've multiple csv files in folder like employee.csv, student.csv, etc.,.. with headers
And also I've tables for all the files(Both header and table column name is same).

### employee.csv

id|name|is_active

1|raja|1

2|arun|0

### student.csv

id|name

1|raja

2|arun

### Table Structure:

### emplyee:

id INT, name VARCHAR, is_active BIT

### student:

id INT, name VARCHAR

now I'm trying to do copy activity with all the files using foreach activity,
the student table copied successfully, but the employee table was not copied its throwing error while reading the employee.csv file.

Error Message:

{"Code":27001,"Message":"ErrorCode=TypeConversionInvalidHexLength,Exception occurred when converting value '0' for column name 'is_active' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'ByteArray' (precision:0, scale:0). Additional info: ","EventType":0,"Category":5,"Data":{},"MsgId":null,"ExceptionType":"Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.PluginRuntimeException","Source":null,"StackTrace":"","InnerEventInfos":[]}

Answer (score 0):

Use **data flow** activity.

In dataflow activity, select Source.

After this select derived column and change datatype of is_active column from BIT to String.

As shown in below screenshot, Salary column has string datatype. So I changed it to integer.
[image]

To modify datatype use expression builder. You can use `toString()`
[image]

[image]

This way you can change datatype before sink activity.

In a last step, provide Sink as postgresql and run pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishekkhandave, But my scenario is generic column, I'm not sure about column name, I'm using first row as a header flag.